# How to dynamically change the values of inputs based on data from a reactive environment?

Tags: r, shiny

Given the following shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

df_fr<-data.table(x1=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),x2=c("1","1","2","2","2","3"))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("x1", "x1", unique(df_fr$x1),multiple=T),
            selectInput("x1", "x1", unique(df_fr$x2),multiple=T)
        ),
        
        mainPanel( plotOutput("plot1") )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    selectedData <- reactive({
        selInputs<-list(input$x1,input$x2)
        req( any( !sapply(selInputs,is.null) ) | any(sapply(selInputs,is.null)) )
        
        df_fr[(if( is.null(input$x1) ) {T} else {x1 %in% input$x1})
            & (if( is.null(input$x2) ) {T} else {x2 %in% input$x2})
        ]
    })
    
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot(table(selectedData()))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want that if I choose option 'a' for 'x1' that only '1' and '2' show up as possible options for 'x2'.
The other way arround, I choose '3' for 'x2' I want that programm shows only 'b' as possible options for 'x1'. So, changing one input should restrict all other inputs to the values that are defined in the data table. Is that possible? If yes, how? I tried already an observed-block which accesses selectedData(). This did not work, unfortunatly.

Thank you! I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Hi, have a look at my response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801841/download-filtered-tableoutput-in-shiny?noredirect=1#comment114573017_64801841

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to use `updateSelectInput()`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df_fr<-data.table(x1=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),x2=c("1","1","2","2","2","3"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x1", "x1", unique(df_fr$x1),selected=NULL, multiple=T),
      selectInput("x2", "x2", unique(df_fr$x2),selected=NULL, multiple=T)
    ),
    
    mainPanel( plotOutput("plot1") )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  DF <- reactiveValues(data1 = NULL,
                       data2 = NULL)
  
  observe({
    
    if (is.null(input$x1)) {
      DF$data1 <- df_fr
    }else DF$data1 <- df_fr[x1 %in% input$x1,]

    if (is.null(input$x2)) {
      DF$data2 <- df_fr
    }else DF$data2 <- df_fr[x2 %in% input$x2,]
    
    if (is.null(input$x2)){
      if (is.null(input$x1)) {
        updateSelectInput(session, inputId="x2", choices=unique(df_fr$x2))
      }else updateSelectInput(session, inputId="x2", choices=unique(DF$data1$x2))
    }
  
    if (is.null(input$x1)){
      if (is.null(input$x2)) {
        updateSelectInput(session, inputId="x1", choices=unique(df_fr$x1))
      }else updateSelectInput(session, inputId="x1", choices=unique(DF$data2$x1))
    }

  })
  
  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$x1,input$x2)
   
    df_fr[(x2 %in% input$x2) & (x1 %in% input$x1),]
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(selectedData())
    ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x=x1,y=x2)) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```